# Removing some text data in HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apex-code

I am working on visualforce pages. below is given the part of HTML file code that has been generated after executing the apex code.

```
<table class="detailList" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr></tr>
<tr>
    <td class="labelCol"></td>
    <td class="dataCol col02">  userName <a href="www.example.com"></a></td>
    <td class="labelCol"></td> <td class="dataCol"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="labelCol"></td>
    <td class="dataCol col02"><a href="mailto:xyz@gmail.com"></a></td>
    <td class="labelCol"></td>
    <td class="dataCol"></td>
 </tr>  
</table>
```

I want to remove the userName anchor tag from this page which is coded in line# 6 whose class Name is "dataCol col02", and there is another anchor tag with the same class name "dataCol col02" at line# 11. keep it in mind that this html is generated by executing an APEX code. Kindly guide me how could i remove the anchor tag at line#6 only..

Comment: So what should be removed finally? text or the anchor link?

Comment: There is an empty <tr></tr> tag?

Comment: @undefined the anchor tag should be removed

Comment: @Rumplin i have removed data from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$(function(){
  $(".dataCol.col02:first a").remove(); 
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amitagrawal/HxfAj/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find`, `first` and `remove` methods.

```
$('.dataCol.col02').first().find('a').remove();
```

In case that you want to remove the `userName` textNode:

```
$('.dataCol.col02').first().contents().filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();
```

Removing all the contents:

```
$('.dataCol.col02').first().empty();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
var anchor = document.getElementsByClassName("col02")[0] //select first matching 'col02'
                     .getElementsByTagName("a")[0]       //select first matching <a>
anchor.parentNode.remove(anchor)
```

You can see it running here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E3Mfw/)

This assumes of course you only ever want to remove from the first instance of something with class='col02', so is not hugely robust. I imagine the fact it's generated means you can't put in more helpful class/id attributes?

On the flipside unlike the other answers it doesn't depend on jquery : )

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$('td.dataCol.col02').eq(0).find('a').remove();
```

or if you would like to empty that td -

```
$('td.dataCol.col02').eq(0).empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table .dataCol.col02:first a").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("tr:eq(1) > td:eq(1)").remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this >>

```
 $(".col02:first > a").remove();
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uguPM/1/)